# Kotlin/Fuel - Unresolved reference: responseString when using apply

Tags: kotlin, fuel

I would like to make creation of FuelManager instance flexible by using apply with it. So, for example, the properties that are common for all instances would be created with this function:

```
fun createFuelManagerInstance(ctx: Ctx, url: String) = FuelManager().apply {
  this.request(Method.POST, url)
  this.timeoutReadInMillisecond = 8_000
  this.timeoutInMillisecond = 4_000
  this.baseHeaders = mapOf(
      "Content-Type" to "application/json",
      "X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret)
  )
}
```

And then I would create an instance and add properties like this for example:

```
val manager = createFuelManagerInstance(ctx, url)
if (payload != null) {
  manager.apply { this.request(Method.POST, url).body(payload.toString()) }
}
```

If I do that, I don't know how to actually call `responseString` to get a response from the request, because I get `Unresolved reference: responseString` if I do this:

```
val (_, response, data) = manager.responseString()
```

What am I doing wrong here, how can I fix this?